# Adding a flag column to SQL query that pulls newest row based on column value

Tags: sql

I have user level data where each row represents an event that happened to that user at a specific time, with a specific characteristic (code). For example, the data below shows 4 users, where events for each user are coded as either A, B, C, X, or Z.

| person_id | event_date | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/23 | X |
| 1 | 1/1/22 | C |
| 1 | 1/1/19 | A |
| 2 | 1/1/21 | Z |
| 2 | 1/1/20 | A |
| 3 | 1/1/19 | B |
| 4 | 1/1/23 | A |
| 4 | 1/1/21 | X |

I want to pull one row per user and want the latest row that is either A, B, or C. BUT I also want to include a flag variable that shows if each user also has a row with an "X" code.

I have a query that gets me the first part of this:

```
select 
    *
from
    (select 
         t.*,
         row_number() over(partition by id
                           order by event_date desc) as rownumber
     from 
         (select *
          from source_table
          where code in ('A', 'B', 'C')) t
     where t.event_date is not null)
where 
    rownumber = 1
```

| person_id | event_date | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/22 | C |
| 2 | 1/1/20 | A |
| 3 | 1/1/19 | B |
| 4 | 1/1/23 | A |

However, I now want to add another column that says if each person also has a row that contains the code 'X', regardless of the date. See the table below for my desired result. How do I edit my query to get this? Thanks!

| person_id | event_date | code | has_x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/22 | C | yes |
| 2 | 1/1/20 | A | no |
| 3 | 1/1/19 | B | no |
| 4 | 1/1/23 | A | yes |

Comment: Can a person have multiple X ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way that you can get it using the following query by considering that a person can have multiple X:

```
 select 
        a.*, case when b.person_id is null then 'no' else 'yes' end having_x
    from
        (select 
             t.*,
             row_number() over(partition by person_id
                               order by event_date desc) as rownumber
         from 
             (select *
              from source_table
              where code in ('A', 'B', 'C')) t
         where t.event_date is not null)a

         left outer join 

    (select distinct person_id from source_table where code='X') b 

    on a.person_id = b.person_id 
    
where rownumber = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your existing query as follows to use conditional aggregation to filter on just the required codes and an additional windowed `Max` to determin the "Has X" flag:

```
select Person_Id, Event_Date, Code, Has_X
from (
  select *, 
    Row_Number() over(
      partition by person_id 
      order by case when code in ('A','B','C') then 0 else 1 end, event_date desc
    ) as rownumber,
    Max(case when code = 'X' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) over(partition by person_id) Has_X
  from t
)t
where rownumber = 1
order by Person_Id;
```